# Type of authentication when using HTTP and websockets

Tags: django, authentication, reactjs, websocket, http-token-authentication

I have a website where I am using regular HTTP API requests **and** a websocket authenticated connection for realtime data.

I am using token authentication for API requests, authenticating websocket connection upon connection via header token.

I would however still like to somehow uniquely identify a "session", if a user was using the same token on two machines. Do I save a random string generated upon login along with the authentication token, to uniquely identify a session?

Or did I go about this the wrong way and is token authentication really just not appropriate for my case?

Because token authentication is just so much easier to implement on the frontend, as I am using React.

Comment: why dont you add ipaddress from your client machine into the token too?

Comment: How does that work when two computers are accessing behind NAT?

Comment: I mean whatever you can get from client computer (IP, MAC Address, etc.). Even you can think about a identifying system, e.g. the first time a client connects you generate an unique id a return it to the client, the client could store that id using cookies. You will know where the client is caming from.
Did you check JSon Web Token system?